# Javascript how to parse JSON with json array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I want to parse this using jQuery or javascript
My JSON generated from the PHP code is as follows:

JSON

```
{
         "user": {
             "name": "John Carter",
             "position": 0,
             "tickets": {
                 "months": [
                     "October",
                     "November"
                 ],
                 "start_Time": "2014-10-02",
                 "end_Time": "2014-11-21",
                 "Open": [
                     "1",
                     "3"
                 ]
             }
         }
}
```

My Javascript

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.report.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'start='+startDate+'&&end='+endDate,
                success: function(response){
                    var json_obj = $.parseJSON(response);
                    for(var i =0; i < json_obj.user.length; i++){
                        //What is the next?
                    }
                }
            });
```

Kindly help.
Thank you !

Comment: Hi @user3312993 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The json returned by jQuery is already a JavaScript object, not a string. You do not have to parse it any further to use it. I'm on a mobile device right now so I can't confirm, but I'm pretty sure you can just do this:

```
success: function(response){
    //try
    var name = response.user.name
    //try this as well
    var name = response.name
}
```

You should be able to print out the name string using console.log() after this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're trying to convert some JSON in string form to an object usable by JS. You can parse a valid JSON string into a JS object by using `JSON.parse(jsonString)`. (Where `jsonString` is a variable containing the string of JSON)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you look over the jquery docs for more info, the best thing you can use is [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) Make sure that in your php script you encode the text as JSON, otherwise jquery will interpret it as plain/text.

Little snippet, which you can also find on the jquery docs..

```
$.ajax( "example.php" )
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Yes but i dont know how to get the value of json object with array.

Comment: It's fetched as object, meaning you can use data.ARRAYKEY to get what you want. Unless the key is an increment value, then you need to use data[KEY]..